# Bokeh CustomJS Callback to change rows of DataFrame when slider moves

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, bokeh, stock

Having a time trying to figure this out:

Have a df with rows of data.  Plotting several lines from the df as shown below:

```
symchart.line(proj_dates, proj_i10, color = "purple", line_width = 2)
symchart.line(proj_dates, proj_ZL, color = "red", line_width = 1)
z0_renderer = symchart.line(proj_dates, proj_Z0, color = "navy", line_width = 1)
symchart.line(proj_dates, proj_ZL, color = "red", line_width = 1)
symchart.line(proj_dates, proj_i90, color = "purple", line_width = 2)
```

The data for each of the lines comes from the following:

```
proj_i10 = interval_df.iloc[1,2:]
proj_ZL = interval_df.iloc[2,2:]
proj_Z0 = interval_df.iloc[3,2:]
proj_ZU = interval_df.iloc[4,2:]
proj_i90 = interval_df.iloc[5,2:]
proj_dates = interval_df.iloc[0,2:]
```

The objective is to move the slider and have each line plot change the row it uses from the df.  So slider value = 1 keeps the above plots.  For each move of the slider the plots move 5 rows each, so slider value = 2 then each line plot skips down 5 rows in the df and redraws the plot.  Slider value stops at 31.

Here's an example of the output without the slider

[image]

Example of the df for the data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the `DataFrame` itself because it's a Python construct and `CustomJS` operates in JavaScript. But it's still possible to achieve the behavior that you want by using views and filters and avoiding changing the whole data. There's a documentation section about it: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#filtering-data

Comment: Yeah I tried to hack it together and failed miserably.  Here's the problem: proj_date has a column of dates and I only want to view the row of data corresponding to the date from proj_date.  Where I'm failing is getting a change in value on the slider to affect a change in the date from proj_date.  I've been searching the documentation for an explanation of that functionality but I'm striking out terribly.  I thought I had it and then, well, didn't.  Is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: I don't know. I cannot really tell anything without a minimal and complete example.